# How to get Socket connect through proxifier

Tags: c++, sockets, proxy

I made a simple program in c++ for connecting to a site and loading a page HTML code or send data using GET/POST requests.
But now I want the program to connect and send/receive data through proxy.
You probably know software like NextVpn and proxifier. when they are running any application which tries to communicate through internet will have to go through these apps.
The problem is that my program connects and communicates directly and my proxy software doesn't interfere.
Communication is done by the socket programming routins (SOCKET class) like this

```
SOCKET sck=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
connect(sck,(SOCKADDR*)(&SockAddr),sizeof(SockAddr));
send(sck,myRequest,strlen(myRequest),0);
```

Any solution?

EDIT: The problem was from NextVPN not the Proxifier itself. It seems that NextVPN lacks functionality in hooking into some programs. First NextVPN finds the program which is trying to connect to a remote address then redirects it to its portable version of proxifier with something named "compose.ns" . Unfortunately it was unable or couldn't detect my app connecting to internet. Instead I used Proxifier itself and it successfully detected my app as it was showing in its connection list.

Comment: Which proxy software are you actually using that is failing? Either it has a bug, or you likely configured it in a way that is making it ignore your app.

Comment: I use NextVPN and that executes Proxifier. No the configuration is on the default. Or if I changed it I'm sure I didn't configure it wrongly. Most other programs works properly like browsers(except opera and dragon) or chat clients like nimbuzz

Comment: Depending on how Proxifier is actually implemented, either it is not hooking into your app correctly, or it replaced the standard WinSock library with a custom one but your app is not using the standard WinSock library to begin with, such as if it is loading another copy of the library from elsewhere on your machine. Use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to see which DLLs your app is actually using.

Comment: I wrote my codes in Borland C++ Builder and run it. Same result. I think Borland uses different libs than VS (My first try was on VS 12)
Don't you think maybe proxy programs have problem with this kind of connections (WinSock) ?

Comment: I should mention I tried this with another proxy software (kerio) again failed.

Comment: C++Builder links to `wsock32.dll`, which is a WinSock 1.x DLL that thunks to `ws2_32.dll`, which is the Winsock 2.x DLL. So as long as Proxifier is hooking into `ws2_32.dll` then there is no reason why it shouldn't be able to detect C++Builder connections. Or, maybe it is because of that thunking that Proxifier does not work correctly, who knows.

Comment: Problem Solved. I will explain it on Post Edit